# Is there any change in TfRecord reading between Tensorflow 1.1 compared with TF 0.9.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

My following code works in TF 0.9.0, but in TF 1.1 it shows the following error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_1_input/batching_shuffling/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 30, current size 0)
>        [[Node: input/batching_shuffling = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input/batching_shuffling/random_shuffle_queue, input/batching_shuffling/n)]]

I cannot figure out what I need to fix to make it work with TF 1.1. Can you please provide me some suggestions?

Here is my code. Sorry it is a little bit long.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import glob
import os

tf_record_dir = os.getcwd() + '/'
batch_size = 30
num_epochs = 100
filename = os.path.join(tf_record_dir, 'train.tfrecords')
def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

def gen_tf_record_files():

    print ('Writing', filename)
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename)
    for index in range(1000):
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={'image_id': _int64_feature(index)
                                                                   }))

        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()

def inputs():

    tfRec_files_list = glob.glob(filename)

    with tf.name_scope('input'):

        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tfRec_files_list, num_epochs=num_epochs, name='string_input_producer')
        im_id = _read_and_decode(filename_queue)

        min_after_dequeue = 10
        capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
        im_ids = tf.train.shuffle_batch([im_id], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=3,
                                               capacity=capacity, enqueue_many=False, min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue, name='batching_shuffling')

    return im_ids

def _read_and_decode(filename_queue):

    # All of the bellow are symbolics
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example,
                                   features={'image_id': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)

                                             })
    im_id = tf.to_int32(features['image_id'], name='ToInt32')

    return im_id


def main(): 
# initialize graph
    gen_tf_record_files()
    g = tf.Graph()
    with g.as_default():
        im_id = inputs()
        if tf.__version__.split('.')[0] == "1":
            init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        else:
            init = tf.initialize_all_variables() #it is deprecated in TF 1.1

        sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False))
        with sess.as_default():
            sess.run(init)
            # Start the queue runners.
            coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
            threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

            im = sess.run(im_id)

main()
```

Comment: A lot of things have been changed in Tensorflow 1.0, you can reference [this post](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration) to migrate your code. Or you may try [this script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/compatibility) to convert your code into Tensorflow 1.0. It should then work in 1.1 as I believe it was only minor fixes for that version.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the script you recommended. Although it looks like the code was converted, the same error still happened with the converted code. I could confirm that the code was converted because init = tf.initialize_all_variables() #it is deprecated in TF 1.1
in the original code was converted to init = tf.global_variables_initializer()  #it is deprecated in TF 1.1